# Costumize firmware TUYA smart switch CB2S

Tags: tuya

I am using tuya smart switches made on CB2S IC in house.

[image]

The problem is that the smart switch with has programed software so, that if you fast turn on and off switch 3 times, it reset smart switch and go to paring mode. This is very disturbing, special for those who have kids which are playing with lights.

Is there any option to change original code to disable this feature and manualy flash CB2S ? I still want to use tuya cloud service.